# Failed to start System Logging Service

Tags: raspbian

After rebooting my RPi 3 it seems that the rsyslogd service fails to start. I have tried the following:

- sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get upgrade
- sudo apt-get install --reinstall rsyslog

The 'sudo systemctl status rsyslog.service' outputs the following:

```
● rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Wed 2018-03-07 17:14:50 EET; 8min ago
     Docs: man:rsyslogd(8)
           http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/
  Process: 5661 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 5661 (code=exited, status=127)

Mar 07 17:14:49 pi systemd[1]: Unit rsyslog.service entered failed state.
Mar 07 17:14:50 pi systemd[1]: rsyslog.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 07 17:14:50 pi systemd[1]: Stopping System Logging Service...
Mar 07 17:14:50 pi systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
Mar 07 17:14:50 pi systemd[1]: rsyslog.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Mar 07 17:14:50 pi systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logging Service.
Mar 07 17:14:50 pi systemd[1]: Unit rsyslog.service entered failed state.
Mar 07 17:14:50 pi systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
Mar 07 17:14:50 pi systemd[1]: rsyslog.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Mar 07 17:14:50 pi systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logging Service.
```

I've also ran a strace on 'rsyslogd -n' and it seems that it fails to load some libraries:

```
$ strace rsyslogd -n
execve("/usr/sbin/rsyslogd", ["rsyslogd", "-n"], [/* 51 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xd8e000
uname({sys="Linux", node="pi", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x76f9f000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=42, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 42, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x76f9e000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0h\5\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 17960, SEEK_SET)               = 17960
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 960) = 960
lseek(3, 17696, SEEK_SET)               = 17696
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\3\f\1\22\4\24"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18920, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 83236, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76f5d000
mprotect(0x76f62000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x76f71000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0x76f71000
mprotect(0x7e98c000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC|PROT_GROWSDOWN) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x76f9e000, 42)                  = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=83277, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 83277, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x76f48000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0l\30\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 90768, SEEK_SET)               = 90768
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1120) = 1120
lseek(3, 90404, SEEK_SET)               = 90404
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=91888, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x76f9e000
mmap2(NULL, 155944, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76f21000
mprotect(0x76f37000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x76f46000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x76f46000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0lY\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 120788, SEEK_SET)              = 120788
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1520) = 1520
lseek(3, 86420, SEEK_SET)               = 86420
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\23\1\24"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=122308, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 160316, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76ef9000
mprotect(0x76f0d000, 65536, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x76f1d000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14000) = 0x76f1d000
mmap2(0x76f1f000, 4668, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x76f1f000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\220\t\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 8660, SEEK_SET)                = 8660
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1160) = 1160
lseek(3, 8328, SEEK_SET)                = 8328
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\23\1\24"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9820, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 73912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76ee6000
mprotect(0x76ee8000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x76ef7000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x76ef7000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0000\30\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 25352, SEEK_SET)               = 25352
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1320) = 1320
lseek(3, 24964, SEEK_SET)               = 24964
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\23\1\24"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26672, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 90684, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76ecf000
mprotect(0x76ed5000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x76ee4000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5000) = 0x76ee4000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libestr.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\274\t\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 8556, SEEK_SET)                = 8556
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1000) = 1000
lseek(3, 8288, SEEK_SET)                = 8288
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9556, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 41060, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76f93000
mprotect(0x76f95000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x76f9c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x76f9c000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libuuid.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\4\17\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 12836, SEEK_SET)               = 12836
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1160) = 1160
lseek(3, 12528, SEEK_SET)               = 12528
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13996, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x76f92000
mmap2(NULL, 78080, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76ebb000
mprotect(0x76ebe000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x76ecd000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x76ecd000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblogging-stdlog.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\30\t\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 16808, SEEK_SET)               = 16808
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1040) = 1040
lseek(3, 16528, SEEK_SET)               = 16528
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=17848, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 49312, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76eae000
mprotect(0x76eb2000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x76eb9000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x76eb9000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjson-c.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0008\"\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 33612, SEEK_SET)               = 33612
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1040) = 1040
lseek(3, 33276, SEEK_SET)               = 33276
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=34652, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 66064, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76e9d000
mprotect(0x76ea5000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x76eac000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7000) = 0x76eac000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0L\204\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 1239936, SEEK_SET)             = 1239936
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 2840) = 2840
lseek(3, 1236500, SEEK_SET)             = 1236500
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\23\1\24"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1242776, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1312152, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76d5c000
mprotect(0x76e87000, 65536, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x76e97000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x12b000) = 0x76e97000
mmap2(0x76e9a000, 9624, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x76e9a000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vfp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=69632, ...}) = 0
open("/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/v7l/neon/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l/neon", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/v7l/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l/vfp", 0x7e98a510)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/v7l/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l", 0x7e98a510)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/neon/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/neon/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/neon/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/neon", 0x7e98a510)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/vfp", 0x7e98a510)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls", 0x7e98a510)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v7l/neon/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l/neon/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v7l/neon/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l/neon", 0x7e98a510)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v7l/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l/vfp", 0x7e98a510)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v7l/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l", 0x7e98a510)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/neon/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/neon/vfp", 0x7e98a510)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/neon/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/neon", 0x7e98a510)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/vfp", 0x7e98a510)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/neon/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/neon", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/v7l", 0x7e98a510)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/neon/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/neon/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/neon/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/neon", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/vfp", 0x7e98a510)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls", 0x7e98a510)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/v7l/neon/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/v7l/neon/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/v7l/neon/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/v7l/neon", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/v7l/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/v7l/vfp", 0x7e98a510)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/v7l/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/v7l", 0x7e98a510)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/neon/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/neon/vfp", 0x7e98a510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/neon/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/neon", 0x7e98a510)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/vfp/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/vfp", 0x7e98a510)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/raise", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
writev(2, [{"rsyslogd", 8}, {": ", 2}, {"error while loading shared libra"..., 36}, {": ", 2}, {"raise", 5}, {": ", 2}, {"cannot open shared object file", 30}, {": ", 2}, {"No such file or directory", 25}, {"\n", 1}], 10rsyslogd: error while loading shared libraries: raise: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
) = 113
exit_group(127)                         = ?
+++ exited with 127 +++
```

The RPi 3 was running fine for a few weeks and yesterday this problem occurred. Any help is much appreciated. If more info is needed I will provide it.

Thank you!

Comment: related: https://serverfault.com/questions/845471/service-start-request-repeated-too-quickly-refusing-to-start-limit